# What is the significance of the ghostly black wolf?

Tags: the-call-of-the-wild

In *The Call of the Wild* there's a ghostly black wolf that appears to Buck whenever he's in a crisis.

What is the significance of this ghostly black wolf?

Comment: ["the primitive call of nature that beckons Buck away from the human world he had always known. Early in the film, that call takes an actual form, as a vision of a black wolf that appears to Buck whenever he’s in a crises. That literal manifestation of the call is strange but effective"](https://www.slashfilm.com/the-call-of-the-wild-review/)